# Is Desktop Google Chrome spell check affected somehow by OS?

Tags: google-chrome, frontend, spell-checking, web-frontend

Does Chrome rely on the operating system to provide spell-checking on the desktop or not? [Here](https://www.google.com/chrome/privacy/whitepaper.html#:%7E:text=Desktop%20versions%20of%20Chrome%20can,by%20Google%20products%20like%20Docs.&text=Mobile%20versions%20of%20Chrome%20rely,system%20to%20provide%20spell%2Dchecking.) it states that is does on mobile. But for desktop it's just stated that spell checks are generate locally by default.

I see that it behaves differently on different machine with the same string. On Mac:
[image]

On one Windows machine:
[image]

On another Windows machine;
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes, since you are using Windows it probably uses the OS.

Longer answer: it depends on a number of factors. First of all if you are using the option for 'enhanced spell check' in Chrome, which uses the a web-service from Google. It also depends on the OS and on the language you've selected.

Chromium documentation states that:

> On Windows, the platform spell checker relies on user-installed language packs. It is possible for a user to enable spell checking in Chrome for a language while not having installed the necessary language pack in the Windows settings.

> For those situations, the spell checker on Windows will first try to use the platform spell checker. For languages where this is not possible, Hunspell will be used instead.

[Source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/components/spellcheck/spellcheck.md)

This can be seen in Chrome itself too, by checking the flags:
chrome://flags/#win-use-native-spellchecker

Comment: Thanks. I am talking about the scenario when `enhanced spell check' is off. Chromium documentation is nice, but is it the same for Chrome itself?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the flags showing the same as stated in the Chromium documentation. Furthermore, see this article from theverge: https://www.theverge.com/2020/5/28/21273934/microsoft-google-chrome-edge-chromium-spellcheck-improvements